# How to set names in a nested list in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames (list1) and another list (list2) with the names that I would like to use in list1, however when I use the following loop I got as return list2:

```
for (j in 1:length(list1)){
    names(list1[[j]]) <- list2[[j]] }
```

Any ideas? when I set the names one by one it doesn't happen:

```
 names(list1[[1]]) <- list2[[1]]
```

Here is an example how my two looks like (I've tried to include the `dput` for my list but it exceed the number of characters):

```
>list1[1]
$cluster.1
$cluster.1[[1]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     2
INMT           2     1
CKB            3     1
NR2E1          4     1
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     1
KIRREL2        7     0

$cluster.1[[2]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     1
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     1

$cluster.1[[3]]
        lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     1
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$cluster.1[[4]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$cluster.1[[5]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     0
INMT           2     1
CKB            3     1
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$cluster.1[[6]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$cluster.1[[7]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     0
INMT           2     1
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

>list2[1]
$cluster.1
[1] "HSP90AB1" "INMT"     "CKB"      "NR2E1"    "ME3"      "FAM162A"  "KIRREL2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because the names on list2, if I replace the names of list2 by numbers the problem disappear

Comment: or use `unname()`.  Can you write this up as a more complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the strings in `list2` are identical to the row names of the data frames in `list1`. Hence, another way to modify the names is

```
names(list1[[1]]) <- rownames(list1[[1]][[1]])
```